# New object getting overwritten with old object in loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, arraylist

My expected output is like this but the new object overwrites the old object if the month is same. Can you spot what to fix?

```
[
December: {
  2: {
    id: 2,
    amount: 1000,
    date: "2020-12-02 17:45:34"
  },
   5: {
    id: 5,
    amount: 200,
    date: "2020-12-10 17:45:34"
  }
},
November: {
  1: {
    id: 1,
    amount: 500,
    date: "2020-11-10 17:45:34"
  },
  4: {
    id: 4,
    amount: 100,
    date: "2020-11-15 17:45:34"
  },
},
October: {
  3: {
    id: 3,
    amount: 500,
    date: "2020-10-20 17:45:34"
  }
}
]
```

This is my code, if you can help. It will be a lot better

```
var data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    amount: 500,
    date: "2020-11-10 17:45:34"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    amount: 1000,
    date: "2020-12-02 17:45:34"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    amount: 500,
    date: "2020-10-20 17:45:34"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    amount: 100,
    date: "2020-11-15 17:45:34"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    amount: 200,
    date: "2020-12-10 17:45:34"
  }
]

var monthNames = [
  "January",
  "February",
  "March",
  "April",
  "May",
  "June",
  "July",
  "August",
  "September",
  "October",
  "November",
  "December"
];
var monthlyData = {};
var date = new Date();
var lastMonthsArray = [];
for (let x = 0; x < 12; x++) {
  var MONTH = monthNames[date.getMonth()];
  var YEAR = date.getFullYear();

  lastMonthsArray.push(MONTH + " " + YEAR);

  for (let i in data) {
    var itemDate = new Date(data[i].date);
    var itemMonth = monthNames[itemDate.getMonth()];
    var itemYear = itemDate.getFullYear();
  
    var list = data[i]
    if (MONTH == itemMonth && YEAR == itemYear) {
      console.log("matched", list.id);
      monthlyData[itemMonth] = {};
      monthlyData[itemMonth][list.id] = {
        amount: list.amount,
        id: list.id,
        date: list.date
      };
      console.log("monthly data", monthlyData);
    }
  }
  date.setMonth(date.getMonth() - 1);
}
```

In my code Ive a data with dates and I want to show all the data but grouping by them with their month names. So basically if their are 6 data from December month they should come inside a key:December named object. But in my code the previous 5 data of december month is getting overwritten by one another and only the sixth data is visible.

Comment: Could you share your expected output? And remove the spammed "aaaa"? And specify which object is overridden by which object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you seem to be overwriting the data each time when you set the new object for each month

```
if (MONTH == itemMonth && YEAR == itemYear) {
  console.log("matched", list.id);

  // added a check to see if the object already exists
  if(!monthlyData[itemMonth])monthlyData[itemMonth] = {};

  monthlyData[itemMonth][list.id] = {
    amount: list.amount,
    id: list.id,
    date: list.date
  };
  console.log("monthly data", monthlyData);
}
```

Comment: Oh yes, my bad. thank you for helping out!